# Display numbers shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to shell scripting within linux and I want to be able to take any 3 numbers from the user and display them in ascending order. I have managed to get it in descending order but not ascending.

Can anyone tell me what changes I must make to the code? Also, if I am doing this inefficiently, please tell me so. I am trying to learn as much as I can.

Thank you!

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#Accepts 3 numbers and displays the number in ascending order                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

echo "Enter the first number"
read num1
echo "Enter the second number"
read num2
echo "Enter the third number"
read num3

allNumbers="$num1 $num2 $num3"

echo $allNumbers|tr " " "\n"|sort|tr "\n" " "
```

Comment: Do not destroy a question after you've got answers.  That is not acceptable behaviour (regardless of who has provided the answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sorting numbers, you should use `sort -n`. For descending, use `sort -nr`

Comment: @Teddy13 Your comments are useless

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $(printf "%s\n" $num1 $num2 $num3 | sort -n)
```

The `printf` command splits the output onto 3 lines; `sort -n` sorts in ascending numeric order; the `echo $(...)` flattens the output from sort onto a single line.